# R packages not loading via library()

Tags: r

I have been experiencing the problem of not being able to load package libraries in R. The packages install fine via instal.packages(), but I get the error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘adegenet’ in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
shared object ‘httpuv.so’ not found
Error: package ‘adegenet’ could not be loaded
```

When I attempt to load the package 'adegenet' (and any other packages).

I recall this behaviour started to occur when I used remove.packages() to remove shiny in order to install the development version on GitHub (shiny-Incubator).

I am unsure as to what is going on. Any ideas on how to restore everything? I updated to the most recent R version, but this did not fix things.

Comment: do you know where the library was installed? and is that directory in .libPaths() ?

Comment: @dww Thanks! This worked! How did you know that the issue was with Rcpp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that during your uninstallation procedure you managed to remove a component of httpuv and/or Rcpp. This should get things working again:

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp", "httpuv"))
```